# Changing the anchors on a kineticJS canvas to arrows?

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop, image-resizing, kineticjs

I have been playing about with kineticjs and the canvas as of the last couple of days. I have a drag and drop canvas that loads a resizable image. the anchors on the resizable image are circles:

```
var anchor;

  function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
    var stage = group.getStage();
    var layer = group.getLayer();

    anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      stroke: "#666",
      fill: "#ddd",
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: 8,
      name: name,
      draggable: true
            });                   


    anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
      update(group, this);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
      group.setDraggable(false);
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    anchor.on("dragend", function() {
      group.setDraggable(true);
      layer.draw();
    });
    // add hover styling
    anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
      this.setStrokeWidth(4);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
      this.setStrokeWidth(2);
      layer.draw();
    });

    group.add(anchor);


  }
```

I would like to turn them into arrows, or something similar to show users that infact the image is resizeable. Does anyone have a method of doing this or a tutorial that may show me how to either draw arrows or replace the anchors with an image?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to change the new Kinetic.Cirle and it's properties to something like this:

```
var anchor = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      sides: 3,
      rotation: -190,
      radius: 8,
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 2,
      name: name,
      draggable: true
    });
```

Although this is only the beginning, due to having a different rotation on each anchor, you will also have to add more variables to the group of anchors as to have each triangle face the correct direction.

I have only briefly tested this, but I hope it helps as a starting point.

Remember to double check the [Docs](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs).

EDIT: Also see [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-regular-polygon-tutorial/).